# methods defined in xib not working-closed

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xib, icarousel

ive created coverflow effect using icarousel,but i've added two buttons not by programmatically in xib and i defined outlet and action and connected for that buttons..but those buttons are displayed as image and not working...Here is my code in .m file

```
@interface GoldViewController ()<UIActionSheetDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL useButtons;

@end

@implementation GoldViewController

@synthesize carousel1;

-(IBAction)showhome:(id)sender{

ViewController *sec=[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:Nil bundle:Nil];
sec.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentModalViewController:sec animated:YES];

} 

-(IBAction)showback:(id)sender{

CollectionsViewController *sec=[[CollectionsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:Nil bundle:Nil];
sec.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentModalViewController:sec animated:YES];

}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
carousel1.type = iCarouselTypeCylinder;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{ 
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
return NUMBER_OF_ITEMS;
}

- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{

UIImage *buttonImage=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ban.jpg"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"pen.jpg"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"ear1.jpg"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"neck.jpg"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"brac.jpg"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"rings.jpg"],nil];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 250.0f, 320.0f);

[button setImage:(UIImage*)[buttonImage objectAtIndex:index] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
return button;



}

- (CGFloat)carouselItemWidth:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
return ITEM_SPACING;
}



- (BOOL)carousel:(iCarousel *)_carousel shouldSelectItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
if (index == carousel1.currentItemIndex)
{
    NSLog(@"Should select current item");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Should select item number %i", index);
}
return YES;
 }

- (void)carousel:(iCarousel *)_carousel didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
if (index == carousel1.currentItemIndex)
{
    //note, this will only ever happen if useButtons == NO
    //otherwise the button intercepts the tap event
    NSLog(@"Did select current item");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Did select item number %i", index);
}
 }

 @end
```

Comment: So if you set a breakpoint in either of your two "`IBAction`" methods, do they hit?  I see you are assigning an action to the "`buttonTapped:`" selector but I don't see where you create the two "other" buttons (or assign their actions).  Are we missing some more of your code?

Comment: thier is button tapped function in that but its performing seperate action for the buttons in coverflow..do i have to define the action of two buttons that i defined in xib under button tapped?..

Comment: if i defined that under that its throwing expected expression but everything the expression related is ok..

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the nib files owner is definitely GoldViewController. Check that you've definitely added the buttons to the nib as buttons and not images.  Make sure touchupinside action on each relevant button is connected to the showhome and showback actions in the nib files owner.

If all of this is ok, its possible that when the view controllers view is being displayed, the iCarousel's view is overlaying your button views. (I seem to recall some issues with iCarousel not laying out the view at runtime to be in the same place as defined in the nib but don't remember details).  To find out - log the frame of the buttons and of the iCarousel view in your viewWillAppear method.